# Trouble connecting .slice Javascript function to my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, slice

I've written a script that slices a mass of text into 1000 character blocks and groups them in an object. Now what I'm trying to do is take all the text that is put in the textarea #PATypes, slice it up into 1000 character blocks, then put each individual block into a cell in a table. Unfortunately, I'm running into trouble- does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

I've written the relevant snippets down below; if you'd like to see the whole thing, check here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ayoformayo/yTcRb/1/

HTML

```
<label for="PATypes">Mass Text PA</label>
<textarea rows="2" cols="20" id="PATypes"></textarea>
<button onclick = "cutUp()">Submit PA</button> 
<table>
<tr>
<td id="PAType=Name=Value1"></td>
<td id="PAType=Name=Value2"></td>
<td id="PAType=Name=Value3"></td>
<td id="PAType=Name=Value4"></td>
<td id="PAType=Name=Value5"></td>
<td id="PAType=Name=Value6"></td>
</tr>
</table
```

Javascript

```
function cutUp(){
    var chunks = [];
    var my_long_string = document.getElementById('PATypes').value;
    var i = 0;
    var n = 0;
    while(n < my_long_string.length) {
        n = 1000 * i;
        chunks.push(my_long_string.slice(n, n + 1000));
        i++;
    }
    document.getElementById('PAType=Name=Value4').innerHTML = chunks[0];
    document.getElementById('PAType=Name=Value5').innerHTML = chunks[1];
    document.getElementById('PAType=Name=Value6').innerHTML = chunks[2];
}​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you've defined your `cutUp` function in an `onload` handler in the jsFiddle. You need to select a *no wrap* option from the menu on the left.

Another issue is that your `chunks` array will always have an empty string at the end. You can fix that by incrementing `n` before the next evaluation of the `while`.

```
var n = 0
,   chunks = [];

while(n < my_long_string.length) { // ----v---increment n
    chunks.push(my_long_string.slice(n, n += 1000));
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/UFTjJ/

Or if you don't like the placement of the assignment, do it after...

```
while(n < my_long_string.length) {
    chunks.push(my_long_string.slice(n, n + 1000));
    n += 1000;
}
```